# Can a woman be a Nazir?

Tags: women, nozir

We know that a man can be a *nazir*- is it also possible that a woman can be a *nazir*?

Comment: You're welcome. You may find https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1081/759 or https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/140/759 interesting as well. I agree with you wholeheartedly that people who don't know the answer to this question are too easy to find, and that the point is well taken, but that doesn't mean our site format is the best place to do so, unless you can [edit] to improve the question quality, which is certainly possible. (Incidentally, the IMO better version of this point is in "Can thread alone become Tamei with Tzaraat Begadim?")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! It says so **explicitly** in the Torah.

[Numbers: 6:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> דַּבֵּר֙ אֶל־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל וְאָמַרְתָּ֖ אֲלֵהֶ֑ם אִ֣ישׁ **אֽוֹ־אִשָּׁ֗ה** כִּ֤י יַפְלִא֙ לִנְדֹּר֙ נֶ֣דֶר נָזִ֔יר לְהַזִּ֖יר לַֽיהוָֽה׃
>
> Speak to the Israelites and say to them: If anyone, man **or woman**, explicitly utters a nazirite’s vow, to set himself apart for the LORD

Comment: Anecdotally, someone asked a well-known rabbi (I forget who; I vaguely remember it being R. Hershel Schechter) this same question and the rabbi responded with this exact reply and emphasis!

Comment: @Oliver I can testify that someone actually asked me this question on Erev Rosh Hashana this year, regarding whether a woman needed to say the "Nezirut" parts of Hatarat Nedarim. Boy, was I ready with a Chumash!

Comment: סיפור שקראתי על המהר"ם שיק (מתלמידי החת"ס) ששמע יום אחד את תלמידיו מתדיינים האם אשה יכולה להיות נזירה, ומצאו כמה ראיות עקיפות שאין מניעה והתפלאו מדוע זה לא נתפרש במשנה במישרין ושאלו לחוות דעתו של רבם. וכך אמר הוא להם; יש לי בבית ספר קטן הנקרא "תורת משה" ומצאתי שכבר נתפרש בו "איש או אשה כי יפליא לנדור נדר נזיר להזיר לה'". and as the story was told to me, it concluded with the words ואינו מביא שום ראיה לדבריו!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I've also heard a version of this, as a Yeshivish legend about someone writing a giant kuntres on the topic and then being shown the pasuk...

Comment: @chortkov2 Plot twist: the questioner is the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

According to Josephus [BJ 2:15, 1], in the years preceding the Destruction in the year 70, Princess Berenice of Judea took a Nazarite vow.

Comment: I don't think this adds anything to the previous answer...

Comment: An example is a convincing addition to pure theory.

Comment: If you needed evidence, the Gemara discusses Queen Helenea who became a Nezirah. But as the first answer correctly cites, from the very place we know of a Nazir, we know a Nezirah.

Comment: This is also meaningless, because somebody historically taking the vow does not in any way indicate the validity of said vow, which was the question posed.