# Does every korban nedava need nesachim?

Tags: korban

My understanding is that there are 3 kinds of nedavos-Olah, Mincha, and shelamim. Do olos and shelamim need nesachim?

Comment: Just FYI there's a fourth type of _n'dava_ according to some _tanaim_: _asham taluy_. But I'm pretty sure we don't rule that way.

Comment: וַעֲשִׂיתֶם אִשֶּׁה לַיהוָה, עֹלָה אוֹ-זֶבַח, לְפַלֵּא-נֶדֶר אוֹ בִנְדָבָה, אוֹ בְּמֹעֲדֵיכֶם--לַעֲשׂוֹת רֵיחַ נִיחֹחַ, לַיהוָה, מִן-הַבָּקָר, אוֹ מִן-הַצֹּאן.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98304/759

Answer (score 1):

[Rambam, Hil. Maaseh Hakorbanos 2:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1017014/jewish/Maaseh-Hakorbanot-Chapter-2.htm#v2):

> אֵין טָעוּן נְסָכִין אֶלָּא עוֹלַת בְּהֵמָה וּשְׁלָמִים בִּלְבַד בֵּין הָיוּ קָרְבַּן צִבּוּר אוֹ קָרְבַּן יָחִיד... הוֹאִיל וְהֵן עוֹלוֹת טְעוּנִים נְסָכִים. אֲבָל הָעוֹף... אֵין מְבִיאִין עִמָּהֶם נְסָכִים
>
> Accompanying offerings are required only for an animal brought as a burnt-offering or as a peace-offering. Whether it was a communal sacrifice, an individual sacrifice... since it was a burnt-offering, it requires the accompanying offerings. Accompanying offerings are not brought for [sacrifices of] fowl...

So every shelamim requires nesachim. Among olos, only animal olos require nesachim, not bird olos. (The nesachim don't necessarily have to be brought at the same time as the korban, though (ibid. halachah 12).)

There are some cases where the owner of the korban doesn't have to bring nesachim, and they're instead brought from communal funds. Examples include when a non-Jew brings a korban (ibid. 3:5), when a person has leftover money that goes into the "nedavah" boxes in the Beis Hamikdash, the funds from which are used to purchase olos (ibid. 3:7), and where a person finds a lost animal that might have been an olah or a shelamim (Hil. Pesulei Hamukdashin 6:18).

Comment: Why are you not citing the pasuk??

Answer (score -2):

It  says [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94) and [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D) does need nesochim.

נסכים - יחד עם קורבן השלמים מביאים יין, ומנסכים (שופכים) אותו על גבי המזבח. כמו כן מביאים מנחת נסכים - מנחה העשויה מסולת חטים ושמן המעורבים זה בזה, ומקטירים אותה על גבי המזבח. הכמויות המדויקות של הסולת, היין והשמן תלויים במין הבהמה הקרבה כשלמים.

נסכים - יחד עם קורבן העולה מביאים יין, ומנסכים (שופכים) אותו על גבי המזבח. כמו כן מביאים מנחת נסכים - מנחה העשויה מסולת חטים ושמן המעורבים זה בזה, ומקטירים אותה על גבי המזבח. הכמויות המדויקות של הסולת, היין והשמן תלויות במין הבהמה הקרבה כעולה.